# Call Android UI component in RN Project: Error - java.lang.String can not be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray

Tags: android, reactjs

I've created an Adroid UI component(`MyRCTImageView`) so that it can be called in my react native project. But when I call the component, I get this error

`Error while updating property of 'src' of a view managed by MyRCTImageView
java.lang.String can not be cast to com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableArray`

Here is the usage of component `MyRCTImageVIew`.

```js
// App.js
import ImageView from './ImageView';
...
render(){
   return(
       <ImageView
            src={this.state.imageSrc}
            borderRadius={this.state.borderRadius}
            resizeMode={this.state.resizeMode}
       />
   );
}
```

```js
//ImageView.js
let iface = {
name: 'ImageView',
    propTypes: {
        src: PropTypes.string,
        borderRadius: PropTypes.number,
        resizeMode: PropTypes.oneOf(['cover', 'contain', 'stretch']),
        ...ViewPropTypes, // include the default view properties
    },
};
const ImageView = requireNativeComponent('MyRCTImageView',iface);
export default ImageView;
```

How to solve the problem? Thank U.

Comment: You're passing a String where it expects an array.  Pass an array.

Comment: @GabeSechan   Can you tell more about it ? I've tried to use this.state={imgSrc:[require('./xx.jpg')]}, but it doesn't work